# Align title box and text with horizontal lines in mdframed

Tags: mdframed

I found a neat [solution](https://texblog.org/2015/09/30/fancy-boxes-for-theorem-lemma-and-proof-with-mdframed/) using `mdframed` to make boxes for theorems, lemmas, and proofs. As brilliant as this solution is, I wonder if it is possible to align the title with the horizontal lines of the boxes (through the center). This is probably made look like this by design but I cannot help to wonder what it would look like aligned.

MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
%%%
\newcounter{theo}[section]\setcounter{theo}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetheo}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{theo}}
\newenvironment{theo}[2][]{%
\refstepcounter{theo}%
\ifstrempty{#1}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=blue!20]
{\strut Theorem~\thetheo};}}
}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=blue!20]
{\strut Theorem~\thetheo:~#1};}}%
}%
\mdfsetup{innertopmargin=10pt,linecolor=blue!20,%
linewidth=2pt,topline=true,%
frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax
}
\begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
\label{#2}}{\end{mdframed}}
%%%

\title{FANCY MDFRAMED ALIGNMENT TEST}
\author{John Doe}
\date{January 2022}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{theo}

TEST.

\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

- Is it possible to align the title text and box with the horizontal lines? In other words, is it possible to shift it up a bit?

I tried to ask a question on the solution site but it never appeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example from texblog is mentioned in the [mdframed manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed/mdframed.pdf) (page 21). The manual also contains another example where the title box is centered on the top line, on page 27. You can adjust this other example to get the desired result.

The example draws the title node using the `singleextra` option. This 'family' of `extra` keys (extra, singleextra, firstextra, secondextra, middleextra) defines points `(P)` and `(O)` on the frame, where the intersection of `(P)` and `(O)`, i.e., `(P-|O)`, is the top corner, as used in the example in the manual. The idea is to draw the title node with this coordinate as position, i.e., `\node at (P-|O)`.

Then you need to set some options for the title node. Important is `anchor=west` which causes the left side of the frame to be placed at the specified position `(P-|O)`, as the default `center` placement would cause the node to expand to the left if the title is longer. Furthermore you can use `xshift` as in the manual to put the title not exactly on the corner but a bit inside. Finally the box can be made a bit more tight with `inner sep=0.5mm`. This looks nice vertically, but horizontally it is a bit too tight, therefore you can add some `\hspace` before and after the theorem title. Finally set some `innertopmargin` to shift the contents down (because the title overlaps the content box) and that's it.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
%%%
\newcounter{theo}[section]\setcounter{theo}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetheo}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{theo}}
\newenvironment{theo}[2][]{%
\refstepcounter{theo}%
\ifstrempty{#1}%
{\mdfsetup{%
singleextra={\node[anchor=west,xshift=5mm,rectangle,fill=blue!20,inner sep=0.5mm] at (P-|O) %
{\hspace*{5pt}\strut Theorem~\thetheo\hspace*{5pt}};}}%
}%
{\mdfsetup{%
innertopmargin=2cm,
singleextra={\node[anchor=west,xshift=5mm,rectangle,fill=blue!20,inner sep=0.5mm] at (P-|O) %
{\hspace*{5pt}\strut Theorem~\thetheo:~#1\hspace*{5pt}};}}%
}%
\mdfsetup{linecolor=blue!20,%
linewidth=2pt,topline=true,%
innertopmargin=1.5Em,
}
\begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
\label{#2}}{\end{mdframed}}
%%%

\title{FANCY MDFRAMED ALIGNMENT TEST}
\author{John Doe}
\date{January 2022}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{theo}[Pythagoras]{thm:t1}
TEST.
\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

Below a version (for the definition with an explicit title) that is centered on the middle of the bar in the lower case `e`, using `text height` and `text depth` with values found by trial and error. I'm not sure it is much better, I think the original is preferred.

```
\mdfsetup{%
extra={\node[anchor=west,xshift=5mm,rectangle,fill=blue!20,inner sep=0.5mm,text height=7pt,text depth=2.5pt] at (P-|O) %
{\hspace*{5pt}\strut Theorem~\thetheo:~#1\hspace*{5pt}};}}%
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @Marijn. That is a brilliant solution, and I also appreciate that you took your time to explain the steps. The title text does not however seem to be perfectly vertically. Is it possible to use `yshift` for that purpose (i.e. to shift the title text a bit down)?

Comment: Also, the previous solution breaks across pages but with the new solution the title text and box disappear while the main box remains. Is there perhaps a way around it? :)

Comment: @naughty_waves the box is exactly on the middle of the line and the text is exactly in the middle of the box, but maybe not in the way you expect - if you measure from the top of the capital `T` or `P` the distance up is exactly equal to the distance from the bottom of the `y` to the bottom of the box. But indeed the distance from for example the `a` or `o` up is slightly larger than down, i.e., the center of the smaller letters is not in the center of the box. I'll try to check if this can be easily changed.

Comment: Repeating the title might work if you replace `singleextra` with just `extra`.

Comment: @naughty_waves see the edit for vertically centered text (I also used `extra` there instead of `singleextra`).

Comment: Thank you again, @Marijn. `extra` appears to solve the issue with the disappearing title when breaking pages but also introduces another issue as it is repeated on the next page.

Comment: @naughty_waves I thought that was the idea? If you want the title only on the first page you use `singleextra` (or `firstextra`), and if you want the title repeated on the next page you use `extra`.

Comment: Thank you for a third time, @Marijn! The title disappeared completely when using `singleextra` but occurred twice (on both pages) if instead `extra` was used. `firstextra` solved it though so it only appears once (on the first page).

Comment: However, `firstextra` appears to remove the title text and box if it is only on one page (no page breaking). Strange.

Comment: Looked through the `mdframed` manual and it is not strange at all. `firstextra` appears to only work for a splitted frame, so that explains why the non splitted frames do not have any title box. @Marijn, perhaps you know a way to identify a splitted frame?